# Compiler error when calling a function that returns a 12-member tuple

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I'm importing an interface from `@uniswap/v3-periphery`—specifically, the [`INonfungiblePositionManager` interface](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol)—and I'm attempting to call [the `positions` function](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol#L61) from my contract. This function returns a tuple with twelve members and is causing me problems. When I compile this code:

```
function getLiquidityFromPositionManager(uint256 tokenId) private view returns (uint128) {
    INonfungiblePositionManager manager = INonfungiblePositionManager(msg.sender);
    (
        /* uint96 nonce */,
        /* address operator */,
        /* address token0 */,
        /* address token1 */,
        /* uint24 fee */,
        /* int24 tickLower */,
        /* int24 tickUpper */,
        uint128 liquidity,
        /* uint256 feeGrowthInside0LastX128 */,
        /* uint256 feeGrowthInside1LastX128 */,
        /* uint128 tokensOwed0 */,
        /* uint128 tokensOwed1 */
    ) = manager.positions(tokenId);
    return liquidity;
}
```

using compiler version 0.8.12, I get the following compiler error:

> CompilerError: Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly: Variable headStart is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack.

I've googled this error and found a lot of results, but they all seem to be related to passing too many arguments to a function rather than receiving too many from the return value. Regardless, I can't control the signature of this function because I don't control the contract. Is there any way for me to change the way I'm calling this function so that I don't see this compiler error? I tried writing something like this:

```
uint128 liquidity = manager.positions(tokenId)[7];
```

Obviously this doesn't compile, but I'm wondering if there's some alternate syntax that would appease the compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `(_, _, thirdVal, _, ...)` might do the trick. Just have the right amount of understcores

Comment: Can't seem to make that work. Compiler is telling me `undeclared identifier` for the underscores.

Comment: I believe there is no underscore, only commas. Like (,,thirdVal,...,)

Comment: Yeah, commas without underscores is what I am using now and I'm receiving the compiler error.